# Binding click to nested ul's

Tags: jquery

I am parsing a markdown file with nested uls to create an accordion style documentation system where you can click on each element that is followed by a ul and expand to see it's contents.

The structure is roughly:

```
h4 (click to expand)
  ul
    li (click to expand)
      ul
        li (click to expand)
          ul
```

Here's my code:

```
$('li').each(function(){
  if($(this).children().is('ul')) {
  $(this).addClass('link').bind('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropogation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  }); }
});
```

Without stopPropigation() in there when I click on the second li trigger (level 2?) it does expand it's contents but also collapses the parent which, obviously, makes it a moot action. If I use stopProp it kills the function all together.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/

Comment: Wow - on taget. Thanks Sir! for the sake of displaying the solution:
    $('li').click(function(ev) {
      $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
      ev.stopPropagation();
    });​

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/H3SAy/2/):

```
$("li").click(function(event) {
    if (event.srcElement = event.currentTarget) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
$('li').has('ul').addClass('link').click(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

That way you're only even targeting the li's with ul's so should work fine.

Hope that helps :)

---

**Edit** - This would also close any open children:

```
$('li').has('ul').addClass('link').click(function(){

    var $li = $(this),
        $ul = $li.children('ul');

    if( $li.is('.open') ){
        $ul.slideUp();
        $li.removeClass('open');
        $li.find('li.open').click(); // Also close the open children
    }else{
        $ul.slideDown();
        $li.addClass('open');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier by adopting an inside-out approach to selecting the elements, ie. within an overall wrapper, select the uls then find their parent LIs.

```
$(".listWrapper").find('ul').parent('li').on('click', function(evt){
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    evt.stopPropagation();
}).children('span').addClass('link');
```

If you also want lists under each H4 heading to be collapsible, then  this needs to be done separately.

```
$(".listWrapper").find('ul').prev('h4').addClass('link').on('click', function(evt){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Note: I found spans to be necessary around each "Item with sublist" to allow that text to be selected and thus prevent all sublist text from being underlined. Try is without spans and you will see what I mean. There may well be a better way to achieve the same end.

All demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BDNLR/1/)